# Does potential + ばいい has the same nuance of verb + ばいい

Tags: conditionals, potential-form, ばいい

いいんだよ別に

こっちはおもしろい記事が書ければいいんだから

My understand of the sentence is akin to "It's fine, I won't mind. If I can write an interesting article it will be fine." The character is trying to gather information for an article from a source, but the source refuses. So the characters tells the source this and that he doesn't need the source since he already has information.

However ばいい is typical used for suggestions? How does it fit?

Answer (score 1):

～ばいい can be used for suggestion, too, but here you can translate it literally as "(is) fine if ～". ～ば is a conditional form ("if"), and いい is "fine" or "okay".

> おもしろい記事が書ければいい
>
> It's fine if I can write interesting articles.
> As long as I can write interesting articles, that's enough.